# Unbound local variable handling

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I recently started facing 'Unbound local variable issue' and I have no idea how did manage to code in python so long without knowing how to avoid this issue.

```
r = requests.get('http://xyz.example.com/api/v2/something', verify=False, timeout=10)
    if r.status_code == 200 :
        res = r.json()['result']
if x== 'organization':
    return res

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "test.py", line 74, in <module>
        resolve_name('test','organization')
      File "test.py", line 20, in resolve_name
        return res

UnboundLocalError: local variable 'res' referenced before assignment
```

What is the best way to avoid the 'UnboundlocalError' in this case?

Comment: Please post full stacktrace!

Comment: This code looks mostly correct except for the indentation and the colon at the end of the last line.

Comment: added more details. colon was there by mistake, removed it

Answer (score 0):

So it looks like status code was not 200 and so res was never initialized.
Make sure you initialize res on top. It looks like x has been set to "organization" somewhere above.